# SLURM does not follow requested resources

Tags: ubuntu, slurm

I have the following submission script named "test.sub":

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --workdir=./
#SBATCH -o test.out
#SBATCH --partition=debug
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --requeue
#SBATCH --job-name=test

x=0

while [ $x -le 100 ]; do
   echo "Test $x" >> test.out
   sleep 100
   x=$(($x+1))
done
```

When I submit this job script, the job does start. However, when I check the job's status using `scontrol show job`, I get the following message:

```
...
JobState=RUNNING Reason=None Dependency=(null)
Requeue=1 Restarts=0 BatchFlag=1 Reboot=0 ExitCode=0:0
...
NumNodes=1 NumCPUs=64 CPUs/Task=1 ReqB:S:C:T=0:0:*:*
TRES=cpu=64,node=1
```

Does this mean that the job is using 64 cpus instead of just 1 as specified in the job script? If so, what should I do to address this problem? I have the following SLRUM config file (/etc/slurm-llnl/slurm.conf):

```
ControlMachine=DDHP-P1-server
AuthType=auth/munge
CacheGroups=0
CryptoType=crypto/munge
MpiDefault=none
ProctrackType=proctrack/pgid
ReturnToService=1
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.pid
SlurmctldPort=6816
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurm-llnl/slurmd.pid
SlurmdPort=6817
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmd
SlurmUser=slurm
#StateSaveLocation=/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmctld
StateSaveLocation=/apps2/slurm-llnl/slurmctld
SwitchType=switch/none
TaskPlugin=task/none
InactiveLimit=0
KillWait=30
MinJobAge=300
SlurmctldTimeout=120
SlurmdTimeout=300
Waittime=0
FastSchedule=1
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SchedulerPort=7321
SelectType=select/linear
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
AccountingStoreJobComment=YES
ClusterName=cluster
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=3
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log

#ClusterName=(null) NodeName=DDHP-P1-server slurmd: Considering each NUMA node as a socket
#CPUs=64 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=8 CoresPerSocket=8 ThreadsPerCore=1 RealMemory=257940 TmpDisk=171660

#NodeName=DDHP-P1-server CPUs=64  RealMemory=264131 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=DDHP-P1-server CPUs=64 Sockets=4 CoresPerSocket=8 ThreadsPerCore=2 RealMemory=252000 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=debug Nodes=DDHP-P1-server Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

Thanks for helping me out! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
SelectType=select/linear
```

in your configuration file. It instructs Slurm to allocate nodes to jobs. If you want Slurm to allocate cores, you need

```
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core_Memory
```

See [this documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/cons_res.html) for alternative options for `SelectTypeParameters`

Comment: Thanks! That's all I needed. Worked well :) I just had to modify it to `SelectTypeParameters=CR_CPU` to suit my needs.